# How to get more encapsulation in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, oop, encapsulation

I have recently learned C# fully, approximately. However, in C++ I could implement a better encapsulation when passing objects to methods, with `const` modifier. But in C#, objects can be modified through the reference parameter, such as `Dispose` on `Graphics` object.

I need sometimes more encapsulation. Properties can give a better solution. However, I have found that, for example, the modification to `Form.Location` property or even to its `X` member is not allowed. Although `Form.Location` is `get; set;` property, its members can not be modified. I tried to do as it with a `Point` `{get; set;}` property but I can still modify `X` member.

This is also an issue when a method for example `Dispose`s an object, as eariler mentioned.

How can I implement more encapsulation in C#?

Comment: const correctness is mental masturbation.

Comment: An important point here is reference vs value types. Any type that has value semantics should be immutable.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with encapsulation. It sounds like you are trying to update the X value on a public property of some type and having issues with that?

Comment: @Ritch Huh?! I never thought I'd ever get to hear that...

Comment: @Paul - This could get into chat, but FWIW, I'm of the opinion that it doesn't prevent bugs and 'pure' const/mutable designs (meyers, et al) just add verbosity.

Comment: I'm amazed there are answers to this question, as I can't even figure out what's being asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot the `X` property of `Form.Location`, because `Form.Location` is a property that returns a *value type* (`Point`). As soon as you access `Form.Location`, you get a *copy* of the location; thus, changing something in this *copy* is meaningless. Since `this.Location.X = ...` is an obvious mistake, the C# compiler prevents you from doing it.

You can, however, replace the complete value of `Form.Location`, since its property setter is `public`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // move window to the left edge of the screen
    this.Location = new Point(0, this.Location.Y);    
}
```

or, alternatively,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // move window to the left edge of the screen
    var loc = this.Location;
    loc.X = 0;               // yes, it's a mutable struct
    this.Location = loc;
}
```

---

To get back to your original question: If you want to make an object accessible, but do not want it to be modified, you will need to encapsulate it yourself. For example, if you want the consumers of your class to be able to `Draw` on your `Graphics` object but do not want them to call `Dispose`, just cannot expose the `Graphics` object directly. Instead, you need to *wrap* every method that the consumer is allowed to call:

```
// bad, consumer can do anything with the Graphics object
public Graphics Graphics
{
    get { return graphics; }
}

// good, consumer can only do specific stuff
public void Draw(...)
{
    graphics.Draw(...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two articles discussing why there is no "const" modifier in C#:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgu/archive/2004/04/22/118238.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/01/22/61712.aspx

Designing classes as [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) is sometimes a solution to your problem, but is not always an option, since it does only work on the "class" level, not on the method level. And sometimes you may have to expose a member variable of your class which is not of an immutable type and could therefore be modified from outside.

Best option: live with that, in practice the importance of const-ness is often overrated.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Point { get; }`. It's the `set` that allows modification.

Comment: I know `{get;}`. The property on `Form.Location` is `get; set;` one, and its members can not be modified.

Comment: I think TS just used this as an example, and wants an approach he can use in multiple situations ?